# Update an argument "message" for document handler

Tags: python, bots

Doing a rar jpeg bot. The main idea of it is hiding rar file in a picture, then get a "secret" photo. But I have met a problem on my way to finish the bot.

So, the first time, when I try to run a bot from my pycharm project and follow some steps to hide arhive.The steps are:

1. Upload a rar file (using a document handler)
2. Upload a picture  (using a photo handler)
3. Get a photo (just send the photo from a handler)

I achieve a correct result (get secret photo with changing size of that pic. For example: archive = 1 mb , picture = 200 Kb, The secret picture = 1.2 mb)

But the problem begins, when I try to do the manipulation again, the second time. After manipulating I get a picture with the same size which it had because archive doesn't "upload in a picture".

After long debugging , I understood that when I run the bot the first time, the document handler gets argument "message" of my first archive and keeps it (info of the first archive) on, even if I try to upload the second archive, because there is "message" of the first archive.

Am I rigth, if I think that "message" creates only the first time, when I run it? 
Can you advice me, how I can solve the problem?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def handle_upload_any_doc(message): #HERE, it doesn't update
    try:
            chat_id = message.chat.id
            file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
            filePATHinfo = str(file_info.file_path)
```

I have also tested it and it works fine, like:

1. run the bot
2. do the process of hidding
3. stop the bot
4. run again
5. do the process again

But if don't stop the bot, the arhive doens't upload...

I don't know, should I post a source code? Because the process of hidding works but I onlu have the problem with a "message".